# Get total object count of Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using free version of azure active directory which has limitation to generate total 500K objects. I want to understand what will be counted as object. I want to know

1. How to get total number of objects for azure active directory?
2. If I am using azure ad authentication, will it generate separate object for each access token generated? If this is the case object limit can be reached easily.
3. Which types will be considered as Azure AD object? like user, group etc. It would be helpful If I can get list of all entities which can be considered as object.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we consider the resource with Object ID in Azure AD as Directory Objects, such as users, groups, applications, domains, policies, etc. See [Directory Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#directory_objects).

Currently, we can't list all the Directory Objects. Because the types and structures are complicated.

You can get the object by object ID by using [Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId](http://Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId).

Access token is not stored in your Azure AD and it will expire in 3600 seconds by default. It won't generate a separate object in Azure AD.